# Jackson JSON - @JsonProperty overriding @JsonView?

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, fasterxml, json-view

I have the following class:

```
 class Bean {
    private int x;
    private int y;
    public Bean(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    @JsonProperty("x")
    @JsonView(View1.class)
    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public int getX() {
        return this.x;
    }
    @JsonProperty("y")
    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
    public int getY() {
        return this.y;
    }
}
```

and a view:

```
class View1 {

}
```

I would expect `_mapper.writerWithView(View1.class).writeValueAsString(bean)` to return `{"x":1}`, since `x` is the only value that has the view attached to it, but I get `{"x":1,"y":2}`.

Why does it do this, and how can I make it not do this? I know I can remove the `@JsonProperty("y")`, but I want to still be able to serialize all values if I choose to use a normal writer instead of writerWithView.

Comment: Are u sure that y is not being set elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to disable [`DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/MapperFeature.html#DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION) feature in `_mapper` object.

See my example:

```
ObjectMapper _mapper = new ObjectMapper();
_mapper.disable(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION);
ObjectWriter objectWriter = _mapper.writerWithView(View1.class);

String json = objectWriter.writeValueAsString(bean);
System.out.println(json);
```

Comment: is there a way to disable the `DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION` feature on the writer instead of the mapper?